# Binding data in mschart

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, mschart

I have a question realting to binding data from a database in MSChart. I have a database that contains "Value", "Time", "ID" and "UniqueID". I want to bind the X axis to "Value" and the Y axis to "Time". I use the "ID" to identify all the data that needs to be bound to the chart control. So I query the database for "ID" 1 and retrieve say the first 10 results and bind it to the chart control. The data is bound to Series "Series1". Now I add a new Series "Series2" and I Query the database to "ID" 2 and bind the data to the chart. For somereason when I bind the second query the chart only displays the second set of data.

Could you please direct me to what I am doing wrong.

```
   public void connect()
{
    SqlConnection cn;
    SqlCommand myCommand;

    cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    myCommand = new SqlCommand();

    myCommand.Connection = cn;
    myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 3 [Value],[Time] FROM [dbo].[Table] WHERE [ID] = 1";

    cn.Open();
    SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Value";
    Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Time";


    Chart1.DataSource = myReader;
    Chart1.DataBind();
    cn.Close();
    Chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 51, 25);
}

public void connect2()
{
    SqlConnection cn;
    SqlCommand myCommand;

    cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    myCommand = new SqlCommand();

    myCommand.Connection = cn;
    myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 3 [Value],[Time] FROM [dbo].[Table] WHERE [ID] = 2";

    cn.Open();
    SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Value";
    Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Time";


    Chart1.DataSource = myReader;
    Chart1.DataBind();
    cn.Close();
    Chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 51, 25);
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Chart1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connect();
    connect2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the same series `Series1` with new data.
What you should be doing instead is adding a new series to the chart using `chart1.series.add`

The link below should get you started:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456769%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Quick question, even after changing my code so that connect2() uses "Area2" it still seems to not display both series. Does binding the data mean that it will only use the datasource that was bound the latest. IE connect2()?